# issues with connection to MS SQL connectionstring at GoDaddy

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to add connection string in GoDaddy hosting.
I am using **MS SQL** server database.

I am getting 404 error when trying to enter the website.
When I upload simple site with no sql database and connection - the simple site works good.

I am not sure what to do...
I am giving here picture and descripition in the picture since I dont have enough reputation to post links and pictures

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad8f9.png

When I enter the site I get 404 error

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you, Alon

Comment: I don't see a password in that connection string. But regardless, 404 would not appear to have anything to do with that. I suggest you add some debugging code to your website to send you some messages about whats going on... but 404 indicates it can't even find the document.

Comment: thanks for the response.
I don't think there is need in password since the "Integreted Security" set to false.

regarding the 404 error, you right this error is for missing pages. but I get it from the code.
If I comment out the lines that use the connection string - the page is loading fine.

Regarding the debbugin mode, it set to be working and tell about errors

Comment: SOLVED! I added the password and it worked fine, thanks alot Nick.McDermaid

Comment: integrated=false means you must supply a user name and password. integrated = true means you supply nothing. You never just supply a username